# How widely used is the word "tush"

Tags: etymology, american-english, dialects, yiddish

In my dialect of American English, the word "tush" or "tushy" is a dimminuitive of "rear end" (e.g., something you'd say about a baby, not as harsh as "butt" and a word you aren't ashamed to say to your mother).  The word derives from Yiddish, and I am from a Jewish family in the New York area, so I'm generally understood when I say it.

How broadly is this word understood?  What do folks who don't use it say in its stead?

Comment: This word was rather [prominently featured on Scrubs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsVgi8hoFFc#t=1m31s), and in fact that's where I know it from. I don't think anybody who saw that episode had trouble understading the meaning. The show runs worldwide.

Comment: We knew both "tush" and "tuchas" in rural Iowa in the 1970s.

Comment: UK - I certainly understand it from American TV, but would not use it. 'Bum' is the all-purpose word over here. In BrEng a tushie peg is a tooth.

Comment: In one of the Nero Wolfe novels, Rex Stout has Archie Goodwin use "tush" in a conversation with Wolfe, who protests that it is not a real word.  But Wolfe looks it up, finds out that it is actually a word, and congratulates Archie on, for once, showing Wolfe something about English he hadn't known.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to say how widely it's understood, but I can say this: Whenever I've chosen to use that word, no matter who the listener is, they understand me. No one has ever said to me, "What's a tushie?" On the other hand, maybe context has always been effective in clearly implying the meaning.

As for what words others use instead, I imagine you can find a fairly comprehensive list in a number of locations, but I think what you're really asking is what *euphemisms* are used. Some of these are:

> rear, rear end, seat, bottom, bum, seat cheeks, tail, behind, *derriere*, caboose, booty, trunk

And the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

In New Zealand English it's not used, but given reasonable context it might be understood (ie the meaning guessed).

The nearest equivalent would be "bottie" - we have a lot of diminutives formed with "-ie" like this.

Examples: 
*"Nourishing and soothing, "Sweet As" baby's bottom balm helps keep your baby's bottie sweet as."* - http://www.historicplaces.org.nz/shoponline_2013/healthandbeauty.aspx?sc_lang=en
*"Great for quick nappy changes, with a generous bottie area allowing for bulky nappies, these newborn pants look great..."* - http://www.thebabysroom.co.nz/category/pants

Answer (score 0):

In Hebrew we use the word *'tusik'*  which is like tush and it comes from the Yidish word *'tuches'*. We usually use *tusik* when referring to babies but it can also be used among adults.

Comment: OED **Tush**: Forms:  Also *tushie, tushy*. Etymology: Abbreviation or diminutive of *tuchus[1]* n. slang (chiefly North American). 1962   Amer. Speech 37 205   *Another bilingual children's diminutive, tushie—from Yiddish toches or tuches ‘rump’—has appeared in phrases like tushie slide ‘a slide down a slope on one's bottom’, the delights of which a group of Midwestern Jewish children have, I am told, expressed to their Gentile social workers.* [1] Origin: A borrowing from Yiddish. Etymon: Yiddish *tokhes*

Comment: Does that inform how widely it's used in English?